# Unable to install plotly and cufflinks using conda install

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, conda, cufflinks

I am trying installing plotly and cufflinks packages using conda install. I tried following commands to install the packages. 
Current python version is: 3.7.3

1. conda install plotly
2. conda install -c plotly plotly=4.4.1
3. conda install cufflinks

I am getting following error message.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to repo.anaconda.com timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))"))

I really appreciate for help. Thank You.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007) git issue help? The problem seems to be due to multiple reasons depending on the environment.

Comment: @saurjog : Thank You. Let me go through it and give a try.